# Diagnosing Noise in Op Amp Circuit ~ 22 second peaks

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, photodiode

[image: Noise with 22 second peaks]

[image: Op Amp Circuit for Photodiode]

I'm trying to diagnose the source(s) of noise in this op amp circuit which amplifies the signal from an OPT301M photodiode. The peaks are especially problematic and mysterious. Please excuse the schematic, it got kind of messed up when I finished the PCB incarnation in Fritzing, but it shows the general concept (The variable resistor{VR1} is 100k). What could cause such peaks?

Comment: Does it change with sampling rate when you go much faster to trigger on the spike and display it?

Comment: Does covering the photodiode in any way influence the amplitude of the noise?

Comment: What size signal are we looking at?  What size is the signal you're trying to measure?  What happens when you measure in front of the honking big gain stage?

Comment: How is the photodiode wired in to the circuit?

Comment: That's a pretty bad op amp for single supply

Comment: What’s the time step and Y-axis scale?

Comment: Where does your earth symbol connect to on the power supply?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that Tony Stewart. No it does not AlmostDone. The peaks are about 5v if I remember correctly and the signal I'm trying to measure is a light source so I'm not sure how to say how big it is exactly Scott S. I have actually quit working with this circuit because I've had so many problems with it and the photodiode appears to be compromised so I'm using another which is working well without an external op amp circuit.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention the battery just represents a + and - supply but I hadn't put that in the schematic yet. The time is in seconds and the Y is volts but it got cut off in my picture sorry winny. Considering I'm giving up on this circuit for now (Although I'm still interested in the source of the peaks) I think maybe I should delete this question because the project in this form is not going to progress, assuming that can be done, as really it should be helpful for others.

Comment: What do you think, should I delete this question, or is it perhaps useful still for people, maybe as an example of how not to ask a question (like when you're stressed out and haven't thoroughly checked your visual representations match up with what your talking about) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the photodiode connection, since it is not explicitly shown, but before getting to that, you need to split the power supply for the op amp like this:

[image]

In other words, both positive and negative supplies have to reference ground.

If you choose a single power supply op amp like LM358, you still have to reference it to ground like this:

[image]

Comment: Not a good answer, or a complete answer, as it does not explain how to bias the inputs for bipolar or a single supply.

Comment: @Sparky256 Good point, I was not sure it was needed.

Comment: Aha, thanks sparky. I'm aware of that, I made this schematic before I understood that though. The 'Battery' just represents the power supply which is actually + and - 12V. Besides that I have quit working on this circuit because it seems the photodiode has been compromised somehow and I have several others that are doing a much better job without external op amps